# python csv contactenation issues

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x

HI Im trying to merge 3 columns into a csv file and Im getting an IndexError: list index out of range. I have 9 columns , and the delimiter is |  .

```
import csv

f = open('C:\\diners\\bacon.csv')
csv_f = csv.reader(f)
attendee_emails1 = []
for row in csv_f:
   attendee_emails1.append(row[5]+row[6]+row[7])

print (attendee_emails1)
```

What am I not doing right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify also the delimiter while passing the file object to `reader` method.

```
csv_f = csv.reader(f, delimiter="|")
```

*Code:*

```
import csv
f = open('/home/avinash/Desktop/dh.csv')
csv_f = csv.reader(f, delimiter="|")
attendee_emails1 = []
for row in csv_f:
   attendee_emails1.append(row[5]+row[6]+row[7])

print (attendee_emails1)
```

*Example:*

```
$ cat dh.csv
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9
$ python script.py
['678']
```